# Search in Windows 10 refuses to spell 'github'

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

[This issue ONLY comes up in the windows search](https://youtu.be/9EisXp7slXo), it does not effect any other place I can type. I have autocorrect off, happens regardless of the keyboard I use, etc. Has anyone seen this problem before? It also does this when I try to search 'virtual'.

Without the video: When I go type something in Windows search, example: github, everytime I get to the 't' it moves the cursor to before the t when I continue typing.

example: gihubt

No matter how fast or slow I type it will do this.

Comment: Please fix your link.

Comment: Should be working now

Comment: It says the video format isn't supported.  How about just an image uploaded to imgur?

Comment: Very odd. Just replaced the link with something that should work.

Comment: You have the github virus, lol, strange as hell.

Comment: It would be good to describe the link material in case the link dies. This post is unclear without that demo.

Comment: I'd probably try a new keyboard, and check for software that performs hotkey polling like AutohotKey, etc. I'd guess that the macro for your `t` key contains a left arrow key.

Comment: It's happening when I spam any character more than 4 times as well. (again, only in the windows search)

It's happening with any keyboard I plug in, even after a reboot. I have no macro software.

Comment: Not a solution, but I would try to narrow the problem a bit by using some sort of keystroke visualization program. Knowing what's being pressed might help narrow down culprits (e.g. a bad track pad or another program).

Comment: probably you should open feedback hub and report to MS